# Access a Javascript object from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a javascript script to validate the format of INTL phone numbers. I am trying to combine this with a jquery form validation script. I can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong however.

I created a method for the validation plugin that should just check `iti.isValidNumber()` but this doesn't seem to function properly, any ideas?

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#phone"),
  errorMsg = document.querySelector("#error-msg"),
  validMsg = document.querySelector("#valid-msg");

// here, the index maps to the error code returned from getValidationError - see readme

var errorMap = ["Invalid number", "Invalid country code", "Too short", "Too long", "Invalid number"];
// initialise plugin
var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
  hiddenInput: "full_phone",
  utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/15.0.0/js/utils.js"
});
var reset = function() {
  input.classList.remove("error");
  errorMsg.innerHTML = "";
  errorMsg.classList.add("hide");
  validMsg.classList.add("hide");
};

// on blur: validate
input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  reset();
  if (input.value.trim()) {
    if (iti.isValidNumber()) {
      validMsg.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      input.classList.add("error");
      var errorCode = iti.getValidationError();
      errorMsg.innerHTML = errorMap[errorCode];
      errorMsg.classList.remove("hide");
    }
  }
});
input.addEventListener('change', reset);
input.addEventListener('keyup', reset);

jQuery.validator.addMethod('validatePhone', function() {
  if ($("#phone").iti.isValidNumber()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}, "Number not valid");

$("#infoForm").validate({
  rules: {
    phone: {
      required: true,
      validatePhone: true
    }
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv6tf2mh/4/)

Comment: I'm trying to get it to call this  if (iti.isValidNumber()) { from the javascript just above the part where you said it wasn't valid. I'm defining iti in javascript

Comment: I'm expecting it to be what it's being defined as in JS. #phone is an input field in a form.

Comment: How would you do that within the context of that method for jQuery.validator?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to wrap all of your jQuery code in a "document ready" function so that jQuery can run when it's all done initializing.

Try wrapping everything in

```js
$(function () {
  //all your code here
});
```

---

Also as a side note, you can simplify this bit:

```js
if ($("#phone").iti.isValidNumber()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

to this:

```js
return $(input).iti.isValidNumber();
```

jQuery can accept elements as well as CSS selector strings, so this way you don't need to have the string `'#phone'` in there multiple times.  Since the `isValidNumber()` returns a boolean, you can just use that directly instead of saying "if true then return true, but otherwise (false) return false"

Comment: Okay, I updated the fiddle as you had suggested but the problem is still that jquery cannot access the javascript iti.isValidNumber();

Comment: Oh, sorry - I'm now seeing your issue.  `iti` is not a jquery plugin, so you can't access it from a jQuery object like this.  You either need to pass your element to it without using jQuery, or you need to make it a jQuery plugin.  Right now it seems like the easiest thing would be to not use jQuery.  Without knowing what `iti` is or how it works, that all I can help with right now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing here is because every listener is added before the dom is ready, so no listener is registered.

All you have to do register your events when the DOM is ready,

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wasifali/r5uy2tkw/)

**Like Bellow:**

```
$(function() {
    var input = document.querySelector("#phone"),
        errorMsg = document.querySelector("#error-msg"),
        validMsg = document.querySelector("#valid-msg");
    // here, the index maps to the error code returned from getValidationError - see readme
    var errorMap = ["Invalid number", "Invalid country code", "Too short", "Too long", "Invalid number"];
    // initialise plugin
    var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
        hiddenInput: "full_phone",
        utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/15.0.0/js/utils.js"
    });
    var reset = function() {
        input.classList.remove("error");
        errorMsg.innerHTML = "";
        errorMsg.classList.add("hide");
        validMsg.classList.add("hide");
    };

    // on blur: validate
    input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        reset();
        if (input.value.trim()) {
            if (iti.isValidNumber()) {
                validMsg.classList.remove("hide");
            } else {
                input.classList.add("error");
                var errorCode = iti.getValidationError();
                errorMsg.innerHTML = errorMap[errorCode];
                errorMsg.classList.remove("hide");
            }
        }
    });
    input.addEventListener('change', reset);
    input.addEventListener('keyup', reset);

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('validatePhone', function() {
        if ($("#phone").iti.isValidNumber()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }, "Number not valid");

    $("#infoForm").validate({
        rules: {
            phone: {
                required: true,
                validatePhone: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but keep in mind that the first part of the script is pure javascript and the second part is jquery.so actually your jsfiddle doesn't work and if you look in the console you will see Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValidNumber' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element phone, check the 'validatePhone' method.

Comment: Let me look into it and get back to you with more precise solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up switching to the undocumented jquery version of the intl-tel-input plugin. It's a little odd that it's not documented.